# Is there a way to create a function reference from the methods section inside the data section

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component with list

```
<v-list-item
        v-for="(item, i) in items"
        :key="i"
>
    <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title @click="item.onClick"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```

I have created methods inside `methods:` section

```
methods:{
        openProjects(){
            if (!this.loggedIn) {
                this.$router.push('/projects');
            }
        },
        logout(){
            this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
            if (!this.loggedIn) {
                this.$router.push('/');
            }
        },
    },
```

And now i want to link them with `data`

```
data: () => ({
        items: [
            { onClick: openProjects },
            { onClick: logout},
        ],
    }),
```

Of course, Vue context doesn't see `methods` section inside the `data`. So what is the way to link them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling different methods based on the button clicked, you could call the main method which will delegate the work to other methods based on the arguments passed.

The `methods` section will look like this:

```
methods:{
    mainMethod(methodName){
        switch(methodName){
            case "openProjects":
                this.openProjects();
                break;
            case "logout":
                this.logout();
                break;
        }
    },
    openProjects(){
        if (!this.loggedIn) {
            this.$router.push('/projects');
        }
    },
    logout(){
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
        if (!this.loggedIn) {
            this.$router.push('/');
        }
    },
}
```

In the data section create an array of these method names as

```
data: () => ({
    items: ["openProjects","logout"]
})
```

And in the vue template, simply called the main method as `@click="mainMethod(item)"`

This looks much cleaner than the approach you are looking for.

Comment: @SkaaRJ Yup!  Looks much better

Answer (score 1):

Turn in around why not using a method with a parameter

```
<v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
    <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title @click="handleItem(item)"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>


methods:{
    handleItem(item) {
       this.openProjects(item)
       this.logout()
    }
    openProjects(item){
        // Some logic with item
    },
    logout(){
        // Some logic
    },
```